# Why are my iOS images not appearing when I run my app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a simple dice rolling app but when I run my project, the dice don't appear.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let diceArray = ["dice1", "dice2", "dice3", "dice4", "dice5", "dice6"]

    var randomDiceIndex1: Int = 0
    var randomDiceIndex2: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!

    func updateDiceImages() {

        randomDiceIndex1 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 5)
        randomDiceIndex2 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 5)

        diceImageView1.image = UIImage.init(named: "diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]")
        diceImageView2.image = UIImage.init(named: "diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateDiceImages()
    }

    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        updateDiceImages()
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

        updateDiceImages()
    }
}
```

My app includes a title a button and two dices. When I run everything appears accept the dices.

Comment: Most likely you didn't add an image literally named `"diceArray[randomDiceIndex1].png"` into your app's resource bundle. Remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You must use an array index variable with the correct way, you are using it as string. You should write it like that:

```
diceImageView1.image = UIImage.init(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex1])
diceImageView2.image = UIImage.init(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex1])
```

`"diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]"` - it is a string

`diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]` - this is a string value of element of array where located on the index randomDiceIndex1

Answer (score -2):

"diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]" this should be replaced with **diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]**

UIImage(named: iceArray[randomDiceIndex1])

Comment: Why negative vote, please mention while putting negative vote!  and as         damage name was  "diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]" hardcoded , the  double quotes should removed.